# Installing LG Optimus 2X driver

Tags: windows, drivers, android

When I plug in my LG Optimus 2X Speed to my Windows 7 Professional laptop, it charges, but:

- The device remains unrecognized in the Device Manager
- No removable storage devices appear in the Explorer
- The device does not appear under "running Android devices" from Eclipse ADT

I've tried having Windows look for the driver automatically, but no dice.

How do I install the driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Windows users:**

**Recommended method**

The simplest method is to head over to [LG's UK site for the LGP990](http://www.lg.com/uk/support/product/support-product-profile-mobile-redux.jsp?customerModelCode=LGP990) and grab the "WINDOWS USB Driver". Make sure your phone isn't plugged in before installing the drivers; you can plug it in once the installation wizard finishes.

**Alternative method**

If that doesn't work for you, LG also provides a software updater from which the USB drivers can also be installed (adapted from [this forum post](http://forum.androidcentral.com/other-android-phones/42678-how-install-usb-drivers-lg-optimus-one.html), although it is for a different Optimus model):

1. Make sure the Optimus 2X Speed is not connected to your PC.
2. Download [the **LG Mobile Support Tool** from LG's support website](http://www.lg.com/us/support/mc-support/mobile-phone-support.jsp) and start it with administrator privileges.
3. From the "Options & Help" menu, click "Country & Language", then select "Singapore" and language "English" and press OK.
4. Wait until the application is done communicating, then hit the rather obscure "Install USB driver" button.
5. A list of models appears. The model number of the "Optimux 2X Speed" is **LGP990**, so find it in the list and double-click it.
6. Wait until all the drivers have been installed and you receive a confirmation that everything's finished.
7. Plug the Optimux 2X Speed in via USB and Windows should automatically finish installing the drivers.

When everything's finished, the LG Mobile Support Tool should show that your phone is connected. You may safely close that window. You're all done!

**Troubleshooting for custom ROMs**

Check the Device Manager. When your phone is attached and you can see a "USB Composite Device" that is not properly installed, follow the following steps (adapted from [this forum post](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/36823-usb-mass-storage-doesnt-work/page__p__271456#entry271456)):

1. Right click the "USB Composite Device" with an exclamation point on it and select "Update Driver Software".
2. Select "Browse my computer", then "Let me pick".
3. Choose "Have disk", and browse to where the LG Drivers are installed (by default `C:\Program Files\LG Electronics\LG United Mobile Driver\`) and select `lgbus9x.inf`.
4. Select "LGE Android Platform Composite USB Device" from the list of drivers and press "Next".
5. Wait for the drivers to finish installing. The "USB Composite Device" is now resolved, but some other components now appear as not properly installed. Simply unplug the phone and plugged it back in and it should finish installing correctly.

Comment: I also needed to follow this procedure for my Windows Vista Business machine. I found that the LGP990 was also present in the "Netherlands" list, where I purchased it.

Answer (score 1):

**For Linux users:** the LG Optimus 2X works out of the box, but debugging does not. Follow the instructions [on this blog](http://ficklemind.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-lg-optimus-2x-under-usb-debugging.html) to get that working correctly.

In case that link goes down, it boils down to:

1. Open a text editor with administrative permissions and edit
   `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-android.rules`
2. Enter the following line:
   `BUS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1004", OWNER="`*`<userName>`*`", GROUP="`*`<groupName>`*`"`
   Where:

   - *`<userName>`* is your user name on this machine
   - *`<groupName>`* is the name of the group you belong to on your machine
   - (For completeness, note that the vendor ID of LG is 1004)
3. Save and close this file.
4. Restart the service with:
   `gksudo service udev restart`
5. Unplug the Optimus from USB and plug it in again. If that didn't work, disable and re-enable the USB debugging setting (*Settings* -> *Applications* -> *Development* -> *USB debugging*)

Note that the debugger will *only* work in the specified profile. Repeat step 2 to add multiple users.